# Good food-safe print filament or method?

Tags: safety, filament-choice, food

I want to create a drinking cup that is entirely safe to consume liquids from. I’ve done some research, but I can not seem to find a cheap or easily accessibly food-safe filament. I have also had no luck researching ways to make objects food-safe.

Comment: @Trish. I think that this question more about liquids and about a cup for personal use, therefore it’s different from both two questions aforementioned

Comment: @StepanNovikov - Surely the end result is the same? Food-safe is the same, whether it is for a cup or a plate, for liquid or for solids, for personal or commercial use? The subject may differ, but the practice is still the same, IMHO. Please clarify, if you feel otherwise, or join us in [chat]. Thanks. BTW, I accepted your edit (so that you would get the rep change, for your effort), but rolled back the change as the original title is valid, and not as specific.

Comment: @StepanNovikov Liquid or solid, the question is "is there a food safe material" and "is there a food safe method", which is what the duplicate questions are about.